# Angular document.getElementById and style.display

Tags: angular, getelementbyid

Could someone quickly tell me how to use the following in Angular? Is there an equivalent or can I use just the way it is?

```
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif ?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Use *ngIf in your HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="yourBooleanVariable">...</div>
```

Now, if "yourBooleanVariable" is set to false in your component.ts, the div will not render. If you change that value to true, that div will be shown.

If you only want to change the style, use NgStyle.

Example:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': yourVariable === 'condition' ? 'color1' : 'color2' }"></<div>
```

This is called a ternary operator, which reads as follows:

If 'yourVariable' = 'condition', then the background-color is set to "color1" ELSE the background-color will be set to "color2"